# Stochastic processes particle moving around a circle

Tags: stochastic-processes, proof-explanation

> Consider a particle that moves along a set of $m+1$ nodes placed on a circle labeled $1$ through $m$.  Suppose the probability of moving to either neighbor node is $1/2$.  We want to know the probability that node $i$ is visited last starting at node $0$.  Suppose we move from node $0$ to node $i-1$.  Since neither node $i$ nor $i+1$ has yet been visited it follows that $i$ will be the last node visited if and only if $i+1$ is visited before node $i$.  This is so because in order to visit $i+1$ before $i$ the particle will have to visit all nodes on the counterclockwise path from $i-1$ to $i+1$ before it visits $i$.  **But the probability that a particle at node $i-1$ will visit $i+1$ before $i$ is just the probability that a particle will progress $m-1$ steps in a specified direction before progressing one step in the other direction.  That is, it is equal to the probability that a gambler who starts with $1$ unit, and wins $1$ when a fair coin turns up heads and loses $1$ when it turns up tails, will have his fortune go up by $m-1$ before he goes broke.**

The probability and the gambler analogy both seem wrong to me.

If we have $m+1 = 11$ nodes ($0$ through $10$) and we want to know the probability that $5$ is last given that the particle is in node $4$, then $m-1 = 9$ steps in the counterclockwise direction from $4 \rightarrow^{1} 3 \rightarrow^{2} 2 \rightarrow^{3} 1 \rightarrow^{4} 0 \rightarrow^{5} 10 \rightarrow^{6} 9 \rightarrow^{7} 8 \rightarrow^{8} 7 \rightarrow^{9} 6$ and then one step in the other direction from $6 \rightarrow^{\text{1}} 7$.  I don't understand how "before one step in the other direction" fits into the probability here.  Why does going backwards one step matter?  It seems the probability should be $P(\text{going from $i-1$ to $i+1$ and then getting to $i$ from $i+1$})$ but this can be done in $2$ ways.

For the gambler analogy, the "before going broke" part similarly doesn't seem to relate to the circle nodes.  It seems that the gambler starts from 1 unit, gains m-1 units (moves from $i-1$ to $i+1$) and the "before losing everything" part seems to suggest that the gambler then proceeds all the way back from node $i+1$ to node $i-1$ and then to node $i$.  The two situations don't seem to match.  Why can't the gambler just win one more and be at node $i$ from $i+1$?

Comment: Perhaps interpret 'before he goes broke' as 'instead of going broke'.  Likewise, I think they mean he reaches a point $m-1$ steps in one direction before (or instead of) he reaches a point one step in the other direction.